# One of two destructors is not called during stack unwind

Tags: c++

I have an application written on MS Visual C++ 2005. It had failed on client's computer. I cannot reproduce the fail; all I have for analysis is log created by the application. In the application I have the following fragment:

```
class EntranceLoggerForFunc
{
public:
EntranceLoggerForFunc()
{
    WriteToLog("EntranceLoggerForFunc");
}
~EntranceLoggerForFunc()
{
    WriteToLog("~EntranceLoggerForFunc");
}
}

void Func()
{
    EntranceLoggerForFunc logger;
    ....
    if (<some comdition>)
        Func();
    ....
}

void Func2()
{
    try
    {
        Func();
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        WriteToLog("Exception happened");
    }
}
```

The application is compiled with key /EHa (Enable C++ exceptions with SEH Exceptions'.

In the log I see the following:

EntranceLoggerForFunc
EntranceLoggerForFunc
~EntranceLoggerForFunc
Exception happened

In other words, an exception happened somewhere inside the Func(); and had been caught in Func2(). But why ONLY ONE destructor of the two objects EntranceLoggerForFunc has been called during stack unwind?

Now I have only the following version: stack was somehow damaged (most probably by the same wrong operation that led to the exception), and this is why one of the destructors did not work.

Any other versions?

Comment: Can you post a compilable example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: BTW- please pay attention to always accept your favourite answers on the questions you ask. That's how StackOverflow works. You can mark an answer as 'accepted' by ticking its green tick on the left.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is that `WriteToLog` is the method throwing the exception on it's 4th invocation.

Answer (score 2):

If the exception thrown is not a C++ exception, but a Win32 SEH exception (for example, EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW or EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION), the behavior of exception handling can become... err.. strange.

(This is why EHa is no longer the default setting in Visual Studio 2010)

My guess is that the actual exception is a SEH exception, such as an access violation, which was the result of memory corruption (and therefore the program state was hosed to begin with).

Comment: If it was an SEH exception though I don't believe it would trigger the catch block.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. 'he behavior of exception handling can become... err.. strange' - do you have any links about the problem?

Comment: @JaredPar: You can configure VS to catch SEH exceptions in catch(...) blocks.

Comment: @DeadMG weird that you can do that but it wouldn't run destructors.

Comment: @DeadMG, That was bug in VS2003, but it was fixed later. SEH exceptions are not part of C++ standard and should not be catched with C++ try/catch construct.

Comment: @Dialecticus: You can set it in every version of VS. It's not a bug. Nobody cares if SEH is part of the Standard- the important part is that you can catch SEH exceptions under some compiler settings.

Comment: Here's a link that you should study: http://members.cox.net/doug_web/eh.htm . SEH exception is a natural result of a bug in the code. It's not really an "exception".

Comment: @JaredPar @Dialecticus @KellyLynch: The switch the OP reports, `/EHa`, makes C++ exception catching constructs catch SEH exceptions in VC++.